# Send Microsoft Reports (rdlc) as Email Attachments using Task Scheduler at Regular Intervals

Tags: scheduled-tasks, reportviewer, rdlc

I have "n" number of reports can be displayed in my web application.

Example

**www.example.com/Overview.aspx?Id=1 -- will generate report1
www.example.com/Overview.aspx?Id=2 -- will generate report2 and so on.**

My requirement is to send these reports as email attachments to the selected recipients at regular intervals. For instance I've grouped report1, report2 as daily reports then these two reports must be generated daily at a specified time and to be sent to the specified recipients. I've a separate web page to group these reports and other options like setting intervals(daily, weekly) and these information getting stored in database. I'm planning to create a scheduled task to call web service(asmx) file so that I can call the above mentioned report pages with query string to generate reports and attach them into mails. I don't think that I can call web pages from web service. My only concern is to call the collection of web pages so that I can generate reports and attach them into mail. Is there any other workaround? Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Please look up the link ["How to Configure Report Subscriptions in SQL Reporting Services"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872783.aspx)